# Filtering a dictionary value from a list of dictionary using lambda and filter in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, filter, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries as below:

```
l = [{'abc': 'def'}, {'ghi': 'jul'}, {'Name': 'my-name'}]
```

I want to get the value of the dictionary that has the key 'Name'
Initially I wrote a function as below:

```
def get_json_val(l, key):
    for item in l:
        for k, v in item.iteritems():
            if k == key:
                return v
```

But I want to do it using lambdas and filter in a single line. So, I tried as below to filter out the dictionary:

```
name_lst = filter(lambda item: (k == 'Name' for k in item.iteritems()), l)
```

It is showing the whole list again. Is there a way to get only the value (not dictionary) using lambdas and filter? Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:**
In the first function l is list and 'Name' is passed as key.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't just combining the list to 1 dictionary and using that?

Comment: @SamCraig Yes. This data format I need to pass to somewhere else and also find the value with key 'Name'

Comment: if key in item: return item[key]

Answer (score 1):

Why are you iterating over your dict? That defeats the purpose. Just do

```
[d for d in l if key in d]
```

Or if you feel some compulsion to use lambda and filter:

```
filter(lambda d: key in d, l)
```

Note, these return lists instead of the corresponding value. If you want the value, you'll have to index into the list. Simply out, using a loop is probably the most reasonable approach, just don't iterate over your dict:

```
def f(key, l):
    for d in l:
        if key in d:
            return d[key]
```

Comment: I think you mean: `[d['Name'] for d in list_of_dicts]`

Comment: @KennyOstrom there will *never* be more than one match. A key is either in the dictionary or not. They are NOT the same at all. One is constant time and the other is linear. These are basic facts about dictionaries

Comment: It looks like a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yeah just noticed they want the value, but I stand by my statement that iterating over the items defeats the purpose of a dict in this case

Comment: Oh yeah, the iteritems part needs to go.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga This is good. However, I need the value. So as @Paul-h said, I used `[d['Name'] for d in list_of_dicts]`. Again, this returns a single element list. So, I converted it to a string as  `''.join([d['Name'] for d in list_of_dicts])`. Not sure though if list comprehension returns null value.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your initial code, this should do the same thing

```
>>> l = [{'abc': 'def'}, {'ghi': 'jul'}, {'Name': 'my-name'}]
>>> [i["Name"] for i in l if "Name" in i][0]
'my-name'
```

Your code returns only the first occurence.Using my approach, and probably also if you would use filter, you'll get (first) a list of all  occurrences  than only get the first (if any). This would make it less "efficient" IMHO, so I would probably change your code to be something more like this:

```
def get_json_val(l, key):
    for item in l:
        if not key in item: continue
        return item[key]
```

Comment: The original has well defined behavior in the case that key is not found. The function will simply fall off the end and return None. This will raise an IndexError if it tries to find [][0]

Comment: Agree on the IndexError ... it was just a "quick&dirty" answer, in "real code" I would've check for empty list. My opinion, if you need only the first go with the "method with loop" approach as it has a "fast exit" if you need all the values use the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'abc': 'def'}, {'ghi': 'jul'}, {'Name': 'my-name', "no-name": "bbb"}]
```

I was able to do it in this way,

```
print filter(lambda item: item, map(lambda item: item.get("Name"), l))
```

if I break this down.

First check if item is in the dict or not?

```
fna = lambda item: item.get("Name")
```

then map list of dict to above function.

```
map(fna, l)
```

for above list it will print

> [None, None, 'my-name']

Now we need to eliminate all the None. I am using `filter` with following function

```
fnb = lambda item: item
```

Now if you put all together you have your code in single line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it without lambdas or filter or any of that stuff. Just combine the list of dictionaries to one dictionary, then use that.

```
l = [{'abc': 'def'}, {'ghi': 'jul'}, {'Name': 'my-name'}]
k = {m.keys()[0] : m[m.keys()[0]] for m in l}['Name']
```

Note that this does not change the structure of l.

Answer (score 0):

Don't underestimate the power of `dict.get()`.  What follows is a simplification of a previous answer.  In this case, there is no need for `map`. For the list:

```
l = [{'abc': 'def'}, {'ghi': 'jul'}, {'Name': 'my-name'}]
```

The following produces a list of dictionaries that have the key `'Name'`:

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x.get('Name'), l))
```

From here, you can retrieve the name values for all items in the list:

```
values = [x['Name'] for x in filtered]
```

If there is only one target, as in your example, wrap this all up in one line like this:

```
name = list(filter(lambda x: x.get('Name'), l))[0]['Name']
```

Comment: why would you want to use `.get` instead of the more straightforward `"Name" in x`?